# To run in a time window until midnight

Tags: cron, airflow-scheduler

I have an AirFlow scheduler that I want to run at 13 until midnight from Monday to Saturday. I wrote an expression like this:

```
0 13-0 * * 1-6
```

While trying to validate this in crontab.guru for example I get an error since 0 is smaller than 13:

> https://crontab.guru/

Does anyone know how can I write a valid cron-expression for this type of schedule?

Comment: Is midnight inclusive?

Comment: @kvantour it is :)

Comment: I wonder if it's correct to do something like this: 0 13-23,0 * * 1-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to run your command at minute 00 from 13:00 onwards till midnight (inclusive) on all days except Sundays, then you have to play a trick. It is not possible to define the hour 24 in a crontab. You can define the hour 00, but a crontab of the form

```
0 0,13-23 * * 1-6
```

will run on Monday 00:00 and not on Sunday 00:00 which is what the OP really wants.

Here are two methods you can use:

1. Run two crontabs:

   ```
   0 13-23 * * 1-6
   0 0     * * 2-7
   ```
2. Run a single crontab a minute earlier:

   ```
   59 12-23 * * 1-6
   ```

Answer (score 0):

How about: `0 13-23 * * 1-6`

“At minute 0 past every hour from 13 through 23 on every day-of-week from Monday through Saturday.”

Source: https://crontab.guru/#0_13-23_*_*_1-6

Comment: It's because I night midnight not only 23 :(